# How to store more than 2 values in multimap?

Tags: c++, multimap

im stuck at a problem, How do we store 3 values through multimap. For example one int and 2 c++ strings. How do we store those 3 values. I tried making a struct and storing 2 strings and then passing it in multimap code as

`struct names{ std::string name; std::string secondname; };`
and done with

`multimap<int, names>Multimap;`

first take number from user, second take name from user, third take name form user and then

`Multimap.insert(make_pair(number,{name,secondname}));`

Comment: What is the problem with this `multimap`? `make_pair` won't be able to deduce `names` from `{...}` alone, use `names{...}`.

Comment: Try `Multimap.insert(std::make_pair(number,names{name,secondname}));`  in case make_pair can't deduce the type of the second parameter.

Comment: Here is an example: https://onlinegdb.com/BJFn1DAZv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define type of pair too like this:

```
struct names{ std::string name; std::string secondname; }; 
multimap<int, names>Multimap;

Multimap.insert(make_pair<int, names>(number,{"name","secondname"}) );
// or simply you can use pair() too instead of make_pair()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you can use tuples.

```
multimap<int, std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> Multimap; 
Multimap.insert(make_pair(number, std::make_tuple(name, secondname));
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: Using `emplace`, you can have less tying: `Multimap.emplace(number, names{name, secondname})`, and a plus,this will be constructed in place!

Comment: @Const You right. i just gave him an example. he used insert in his question.